# Attach SQL Server database in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, attachment, smo, detach

I am developing a project in C#. I want to detach and then attach SQL Server database from C# code using SMO. I can detach database, but when I want to attach it, an error occurs:

> Unable to open the physical file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\ghale.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".

Code :

```
OpenFileDialog f = new OpenFileDialog();
f.Title = "sqlbakcup";
f.FileName = "";
f.Filter = @"SQL Backup files (*.BAK) |*.BAK|All files(*.*) |*.*";

if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True");
    ServerConnection serverconn = new ServerConnection(sqlconn);

    Server s = new Server(serverconn);
    s.DetachDatabase("ghale", false);

    //MessageBox.Show("ok");
    SqlConnection sqlconn1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=mydb2;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("ALTER DATABASE mydb2  SET SINGLE_USER with ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE " + "use master  " + "RESTORE DATABASE [mydb2] FROM  DISK = @n WITH REPLACE ", sqlconn1);
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", f.FileName);

    sqlconn1.Open();
    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlconn1.Close();

    SqlConnection sqlconn2 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True");
    ServerConnection serverconn2 = new ServerConnection(sqlconn2);

    Server s1 = new Server(serverconn2);
    s1.AttachDatabase("ghale", new StringCollection {
            @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\ghale.mdf",
            @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\ghale_log.ldf" }, AttachOptions.None);
    //MessageBox.Show("ok");
    MessageBox.Show("OK");
}
```

Comment: What is smo in your post?

Comment: @RBT: SQL Server's Shared Management Objects - a library to manage the server and its database objects

Comment: SMO stands for SQL Server Management Objects

Comment: Ok. Please post the C# code for SMO that you have written to attach the database file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to attach sqlserver database in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39263224/how-to-attach-sqlserver-database-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of observations:

1. The variables `sqlconn2`, `serverconn2`, and `s1` are unnecessary as you can just reuse the variable `s` to re-attach the `ghale` database
2. If I comment out the middle section that restores a backup file to `mydb2`, the re-attaching of the `ghale` database works
3. I suspect you are restoring a `ghale` backup file to the database `mydb2`, if so, if you look at the Database Properties | Files of `mydb2` you will see that it is using the files `ghale.mdf` and `ghale_log.ldf`. As a result you cannot re-attach `ghale.mdf` because that file is now being used by the database `mydb2` hence the Access Denied error message.

**UPDATE**:
I think the following code is what you're trying to accomplish:

```
OpenFileDialog f = new OpenFileDialog();
f.Title = "sqlbakcup";
f.FileName = "";
f.Filter = @"SQL Backup files (*.BAK) |*.BAK|All files(*.*) |*.*";

if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        ServerConnection serverconn = new ServerConnection(sqlconn);

        Server s = new Server(serverconn);
        s.DetachDatabase("ghale", false);

        SqlConnection sqlconn1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=mydb2;Integrated Security=True");

        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(
            "ALTER DATABASE [mydb2] SET SINGLE_USER with ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE use master " 
            + @"RESTORE DATABASE [mydb2] FROM DISK = @n WITH REPLACE, "
            + @"MOVE 'ghale'     TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\mydb2.mdf', "
            + @"MOVE 'ghale_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\mydb2_log.ldf' "
            + @"ALTER DATABASE [mydb2] MODIFY FILE (NAME=N'ghale', NEWNAME=N'mydb2')"
            + @"ALTER DATABASE [mydb2] MODIFY FILE (NAME=N'ghale_log', NEWNAME=N'mydb2_log')",
        sqlconn1);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", f.FileName);

        sqlconn1.Open();
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlconn1.Close();

        s.AttachDatabase("ghale",
                        new StringCollection {
        @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\ghale.mdf",
        @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\ghale_log.ldf" },
                        AttachOptions.None);
    }
}
```

I've updated the `mydb2` database restore sql to use different physical files for data and logs, as well as rename the logical names.

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

The first you should find out your service account of sqlserver,you can see it in Task Manager when you press ctrl+alt+delete at the same time;Then,you must give the read/write privilege of "C:\Murach\SQL Server 2008\Databases" to the service account.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA ...Then right click yourdatabse -> Properties-> Security tab -> continue -> select full control to user